# Migrate to OAuth 2.0 login from openId 2.0

Tags: php, api, oauth

I am using php LightOpenID for implementing google signIn, and I am having no problem in that. But recently I came to know that google  deprecated OpenID 2.0 and soon will stop supporting it . So they are suggesting to migrate form OpenId to OAuth 2.0 login .

https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable I have gone tghrough thsi documentation , but understood a little . I am confused as how to adapt this changes, can I use existing php LightOpenID ? or what is the actual process of migrating without affecting old existing system . Tried googling but none were helpful . Please suggest how to achieve this , and what path should I take ? Any references etc will be helpful

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you work with Google APIs, I think it is better for you to switch to Google+ sign-in. Google consolidates its sign-in features, and will support only Google+ sign in ...

Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration) for the migration details, and [specifically here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in).

Google+ for PHP:
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for implementing g+ signin , is there any php client library ?

Comment: ...and don't forget to mark my answer as "correct" (if it helped you :) )